# Remove DACPAC reference files from project and reference and generate pre-build

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a SQL server database project that I am building using Visual Studio.  The project contains 4 DACPAC references.  The DACPAC files are currently part of the github repository, so could in theory become stale as time goes on.

I'd like to avoid the references becoming stale and not have to store the files in the repo.

Therefore, my question consists of 2 parts:

1. I think I can generate the referenced Dacpacs when developing locally by issuing a pre-build set of commands such as SQlPackage - can anybody think of other approaches that may work?
2. Am I able to do something similar in Azure Devops as a pre-build step, or as part of the build process?

Comment: *The DACPAC files are currently part of the github repository*. So the straightforward solution is to not store DACPACs in the repo but instead **build them along with everything else**. I don't understand where you're having difficulty. Are you having difficulty implementing a YAML pipeline in Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Daniel, we currently have 1 Solution with 1 database project. I had suggested that we could have multiple DB projects in 1 solution and then I could reference the projects as part of the build instead of the dacpac files.  However, it looks like the team want 1 repo per database.  In the Azure side, are you saying that I could somehow build required database references as other artifacts and then reference these in a subsequent step in the build pipeline?